# Get all selected options from a group if select-fields

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

I have a various number of select-fields with ne name **group**

```
<select name="group[1]" onChange="showMeAllSelectedGroups(); return false;">
    <option value="46">Rot</option>
    <option value="1">Blau</option>
</select>


<select name="group[6]" onChange="showMeAllSelectedGroups(); return false;">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

now I need to get all the selected options from every select-field, when one of them is changed.

```
function showMeAllSelectedGroups() {    
    $("select").each(function() {       
        alert($(this).val());
    }); 
}
```

this works fine, but i gives me the values of every select field on the page, I only need to have the selected options of the select-fields with the name **group**

**this does not work:**

```
function showMeAllSelectedGroups() {    
    $("select[name='group']").each(function() {       
        alert($(this).val());
    }); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have select with name `"group[1]"` and `"group[6]"` where as using `name='group'`, I think you are looking for `$("select[name^='group']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others suggest, you need the starts with operator `^`, but to get the number from the `name` you could use regex `/group\[(\d+)\]/`:-

```js
function showMeAllSelectedGroups() {
  $("select[name^='group']").each(function() {
    var number = /group\[(\d+)\]/.exec(this.name)[1];
    $('body').append("<div>group number = " + number + "</div>");
    $('body').append("<div>select value = " + $(this).val() + "</div>");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="group[1]" onChange="showMeAllSelectedGroups(); return false;">
  <option value="46">Rot</option>
  <option value="1">Blau</option>
</select>


<select name="group[6]" onChange="showMeAllSelectedGroups(); return false;">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it did not worked is, `select[name='group']` is wrong selector to target element with name `group[1]` and `group[6]`. `select[name='group']` will only look for element that has `name=group`

You can rather use attribute starts with selector:

```
$("select[name^='group[']").each(function() {       
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: one more question.. is there a way to find out the index of the group[] ?? ... i mean the **6** of **group[6]** ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use start with selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```js
function showMeAllSelectedGroups() {    
    $("select[name^='group']").each(function() {       
        alert($(this).val());
    }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group[1]" onChange="showMeAllSelectedGroups(this); return false;">
    <option value="46">Rot</option>
    <option value="1">Blau</option>
</select>


<select name="group[6]" onChange="showMeAllSelectedGroups(this); return false;">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: one more question.. is there a way to find out the index of the group[] ?? ... i mean the **6** of **group[6]** ?